# T-SQL: Search for specific string from a list in a field

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have to look for a list of words within a database field and get only the fields with exact wording. To be more precise, I need to look for all variant of "P/O Box" in an address field. So, if the field contains "PO", or "BOX", or "P O" or "P/O" etc, it has to be return by the query. This list is contained in a table (there is 14 differents spelling to look for). I tried with CHARINDEX, but address with "POLAR ST." for example, will be return also. Is there a way, without using full-text search, I can extract just the field with the exact spelling of the searched string?

thanks for your time and help

Comment: To Prince's point in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62307995/5790584), trial an error is really the only solution here. If you're looking for anything more fine-grained than that suggestion, please post sample data (as plain text or DDL/DML) that includes most or all of the 14 variations you've identified along with the false positives you're having trouble with, and your attempted query so far.

Comment: Would "c/o Pugilism or Boxing?" match `'P/O Box'` in an address line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no single out of the box solution may available for this.

I would recommend the following way,

1. Gather all the possible variations (For PO Box) in your data
2. Write a query (the one you are using) to filter preferred data
3. Check the query result for unexpected data (Like Polar ST)
4. Then Alter the query to modify the search criteria to avoid this data (Polar ST). **Like**, If 'PO' is your expected variation, I guess then the 3rd char might be
   number (PO12), space (PO 12).  It should not be a alphabetical I hope
   (Like pos). Then you can use this for more finer search criteria.

Even you may have issue with other words too (like 'Box'), so analyze repeatedly to get optimum result.

**Note:** Please refer 'Regular Expression' in Sql Server. You have a ton of options for these kind of searches.

I will be happy if this helps a bit for you.

Comment: ok, thank you for the explanation. Do you know how I can write a query with something like "WHERE Address LIKE tblBOX.poBOX + ' %' ? tblBOX is the table that contains all 14 P/O Box spelling. thanks!

Comment: Please try thisIn the table having the variations of 'Po box' ('tblBOX.poBOX') keep values with %,
eg. insert into tblBOX.poBOX (val) 
values ('PO%'),('PO Box%'), ('P/O%')


SELECT   tab.* FROM tblBOX.poBOX
  CROSS APPLY
  (  -- your query starts here
    SELECT * from addr WHERE addr1 like tblBOX.poBOX.val
 -- your query ends here
  ) AS tab